# postfix + spamassassin check SPF from the email headers

Tags: postfix, spf, spamassassin

I have postfix + spamassassin.

Spamassassin suppose to check the SPF of the sender, but I received following spam:

**belt@example.com** = this is the email on my postfix

```
Return-Path: <leonah@betterway.com.vn>
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.0 (2014-02-07) on
        astra4450.dedicatedpanel.com
X-Spam-Level: ***
X-Spam-Status: No, score=3.4 required=5.0 tests=BAYES_00,
        HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS,HTML_MESSAGE,RCVD_IN_SBL,SPF_HELO_PASS,SPF_PASS,
        TO_IN_SUBJ,TVD_PH_BODY_ACCOUNTS_PRE,T_KAM_HTML_FONT_INVALID,URIBL_BLOCKED,
        URIBL_DBL_MALWARE,URIBL_PH_SURBL,URIBL_SBL,URIBL_SBL_A autolearn=no
        autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0
Delivered-To: belt@example.com
Received: from mail.hostify.vn (mail.hostify.vn [150.95.110.152])
        by mx6.example.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id A0C74100F20F14
        for <belt@example.com>; Wed, 13 Dec 2023 03:26:58 +0200 (EET)
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
        by mail.hostify.vn (Postfix) with ESMTP id 0FFB9166DF7
        for <belt@example.com>; Wed, 13 Dec 2023 08:26:57 +0700 (+07)
Received: from mail.hostify.vn ([127.0.0.1])
        by localhost (mail.hostify.vn [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10032)
        with ESMTP id EaHftMvBvz9k for <belt@example.com>;
        Wed, 13 Dec 2023 08:26:56 +0700 (+07)
Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
        by mail.hostify.vn (Postfix) with ESMTP id 9CEAE167AA0
        for <belt@example.com>; Wed, 13 Dec 2023 08:26:56 +0700 (+07)
X-Virus-Scanned: amavisd-new at hostify.vn
Received: from mail.hostify.vn ([127.0.0.1])
        by localhost (mail.hostify.vn [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10026)
        with ESMTP id Y2hw8khgynlj for <belt@example.com>;
        Wed, 13 Dec 2023 08:26:56 +0700 (+07)
Received: from [88.209.206.208] (unknown [88.209.206.208])
        by mail.hostify.vn (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 9CF741675DA
        for <belt@example.com>; Wed, 13 Dec 2023 08:26:55 +0700 (+07)
From: Admin Helpdesk <admin@example.com>
To: belt@example.com
Subject: Password Verification For belt@example.com
Date: 12 Dec 2023 17:26:54 -0800
Message-ID: <20231212172653.3429FECB7E0715DA@example.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
        boundary="----=_NextPart_000_0012_CFC45DD6.E88DD181"
```

From what I can conclude, the SPF for **leonah@betterway.com.vn** was correct and sender is "spoofed" in the header as **admin@example.com**

However there is no way SPF for **admin@example.com** to be correct.

Today I installed some tool called `pypolicyd-spf`, but as long as I was able to check, it also check only `mail from:` SMTP command and not email headers.

Am I missing something or may be using wrong tool for the job?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lets suppose following:

```
helo spammer.com          << [1]
mail from: me@spammer.com << [2]
rcpt to: user@domain.com
data
from: admin@domain.com    << [3]
to: user@domain.com
subject: spam

spam
.
```

It turns out SPF should be check only on From: field from SMTP connection, e.g. [2].

Often this is same as Return-Path.

Sometimes SPF checks the helo domain [1].

However the from: header from the email [3] is **never** checked.

This means everybody can spoof the sender like this.

In order to mitigate your own domain, you can do DMARC and specify that both addresses must be the same.

In order to mitigate this for domains that you do not own, you can increase the following scores in /etc/mail/spamassassin/local.cf

```
score           SPF_FAIL            0 0 0 4.50
score           SPF_SOFTFAIL        0 0 0 3.50
score           SPF_HELO_FAIL       0 0 0 4.50
score           SPF_HELO_SOFTFAIL   0 0 0 3.50

score           HEADER_FROM_DIFFERENT_DOMAINS   0 0 0 4.50
```

Please note this is bit risky, because sometimes some domains are configured non 100% correctly.

Comment: care to comment about -1 you place?

Answer (score 3):

This is how SPF is supposed to work. From the Introduction of Sender Policy Framework (SPF) ([RFC 7208, 1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-1)):

> This document defines a protocol by which domain owners may authorize
> hosts to use their domain name in the "MAIL FROM" or "HELO" identity.
> Compliant domain holders publish Sender Policy Framework (SPF)
> records specifying which hosts are permitted to use their names, and
> compliant mail receivers use the published SPF records to test the
> authorization of sending Mail Transfer Agents (MTAs) using a given
> "HELO" or "MAIL FROM" identity during a mail transaction.

DMARC ([RFC 7489](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7489.html)) on the other hand enables the sender to publish policies on how they want receivers to handle messages where the `From` header is not *aligned* with either the *envelope sender* (MAIL FROM) passing SPF or a valid DKIM signature.